# "The Left/Right are in tears"

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to say something like "The liberals of US are in tears today over (a political news)".
I want to shorten it to "The left are in tears".
However when I google for that phrase, I see that nobody ever used this sentence. Could you please help me rephrase that?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with *the left are in tears* when a political context is made clear. It would be a mistake to think that the lack of a Google search result indicates something unidiomatic or ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find more Google hits if you search for "the left is in tears". In US English, collective nouns - organisations, teams, political groupings, companies, etc, are almost invariably considered to be singular. Your use of the plural 'are' reflects the British usage, which allows both singular and plural. To answer your question, you can say the left are (or is) in tears, smiling, delighted, unhappy, confused, punching the air, etc, about something, e.g. some political news (not 'a news' - news is uncountable).

Comment: Yep, "the left is in tears" (with quotes) gets me 14 hits, about 8 of which appear to be valid (and non-dupe) uses of the term in the OP's sense.  "The left are in tears" gets me one valid hit.

Comment: Once one eliminates constructions like "the man on the left/right is in tears," the difference in results is slight. ~10 results mostly focused on one usage by Steve Bannon does not make a solid argument for usage. I'd omit the results as inconclusive and keep or expand on the reasoning based on grammar.

Comment: ("The right is/are in tears" doesn't get me anything.  I suspect that this is because the Left is generally portrayed as more emotional than the Right.)

Comment: "Liberals are in tears" gets over 21,000 hits!!!  "Conservatives are in tears" gets 1.

Comment: "Republicans eat shit" (with the quotes) got "About 9,580,000 results", but, even with the quotes,  a lot of them are just pages containing both the name of the party and the vulgar term for faeces.

Comment: I should also say that one of the more refreshing things about Stack Exchange in general is a lack of US political partisanship.